# MSBuild DownloadFile task Illegal characters in path

Tags: msbuild, task

When PackageBaseURL equals to 'https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/AspiraFocus/ClientServicesModule3', there is an error, 'Illegal characters in path' when download file via MSBuild.
But when PackageBaseURL is 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/src', it works well.

Could you tell me why the first one doesn't work?

```
<PackageBaseURL>https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/AspiraFocus/ClientServicesModule3</PackageBaseURL>
<Package>abc.exe</Package >
<Target Name="DownloadPackage">     
    <DownloadFile SourceUrl="$(PackageBaseURL)/$(Package)" DestinationFolder="$(Workspace)">
    </DownloadFile>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround for me was to specify the `DestinationFileName` parameter, like

```
<PackageBaseURL>https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/AspiraFocus/ClientServicesModule3</PackageBaseURL >
<Package>abc.exe</Package >
<Target Name="DownloadPackage">
  <DownloadFile 
    SourceUrl="$(PackageBaseURL)/$(Package)" 
    DestinationFolder="$(Workspace)" 
    DestinationFileName="abc.exe"></DownloadFile>
</Target>
```

Let me try to explain what was causing the issue and why this workaround helped in my case:

- The download server I use responds with [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition), including the suggested file name, e.g. `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="the-file-name.txt"`
- DownloadFile task uses information to determine the file name, see the [description of the DownloadFile task.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/downloadfile-task)

  > By default, the file name is derived from the SourceUrl or the remote
  >   server.
- DownloadFile task gets this information using [ContentDispositionHeaderValue.FileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.contentdispositionheadervalue.filename), see [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/ab7bc2bef6bb55cb6f1c1acec3acd9c2ab319dda/src/Tasks/DownloadFile.cs#L267).
- DownloadFile task uses this value [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to create the destination path.
- Now the problem: The string provided by `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.FileName` is surrounded by quotes, e.g. `"the-file-name.txt"`, and `Path.Combine` throws an exception, because the quotes are illegal characters.
- If you specify `DestinationFile` parameter, the file name is not taken from the Content-Disposition header